# Suggestion Needed for Optimizing a SQL Stored Proc with Loops for Processing Large Data

Tags: performance, optimization

I received the following request from our client:
 
**Get the total number of opens for all the contacts who received at least one email campaigns from us in 2013.**

Additional info:

- Total number of contacts we sent email campaigns to in 2013: 200,000
- Total number of emails sent in 2013: 900
- Each email campaign has a supporting data table that holds the recipient info as well as date sent, opens and clicks stats. Each recipient's info and stats are stored in a separate row of the data table.
- There is master tracking table called campaign_tracker used for tracking all the email addresses that we ever sent an email campaign to. It records the email address of the recipients as well as the corresponding data table name of every email campaign they ever received.

The Problem:
I've written a stored proc that is able to return the correct result, but it is horribly slow in terms of the performance. The code needs to loop through over 270,000 contacts and finds the opens for each of them in all 900 campaign data tables. It has no idea which data table the current contact being checking exists in, so it also needs to loop through all the campaign data tables to figure that out. Since campaign stats are stored in individual data tables, so I don't know how to avoid using loops to get the Opens.

Contact 1 -> Loop through all data tables -> Get Total Opens for Contact 1
Contact 2 -> Loop through all data tables -> Get Total Opens for Contact 2
... ...
Contact N (N=200,000) -> Loop through all data tables -> Get Total Opens for Contact N

Here is the code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Email) As TempID, t.LeadID, t.Email, t.CampaignID, t.DataBaseName, t.DataTableName, 0 AS 'Opens', 0 AS 'Clicks' 
    INTO #temptb
    FROM campaign_tracker t
    INNER JOIN campaigns c ON c.CampaignID = t.CampaignID
    WHERE t.DateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59.999' AND 
            c.CategoryID IN (1,2) AND t.Email IS NOT NULL

    DECLARE @Sqlstr NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @outtb table (OutID INT, OutValue INT)

    DECLARE @INTFlag INT, @Count INT, @Email VARCHAR(500), @DataBaseName VARCHAR(500), @DataTableName VARCHAR(500)  

    SET @INTFlag = 1
    SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temptb)
    WHILE (@INTFlag <= @Count)
    BEGIN
        SET @Email = (SELECT Email FROM #temptb WHERE TempID = @intFlag)
        SET @DataBaseName = (SELECT DataBaseName FROM #temptb WHERE TempID = @intFlag)
        SET @DataTableName = (SELECT DataTableName FROM #temptb WHERE TempID = @intFlag)

        SET @Sqlstr = 'SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@INTFlag) + ', SUM(Opened) FROM ' + @DataBaseName + '.dbo.' + @DataTableName + ' WHERE Email = ''' + @Email + ''''
        INSERT INTO @outtb (OutID, OutValue) EXEC (@Sqlstr) 

        SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    END

    SELECT t.LeadID, t.Email, COUNT(t.Email) AS 'Total Emails Received', SUM(o.OutValue) AS 'Total Opens'
    FROM #temptb t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @outtb o ON o.OutID = t.TempID
    GROUP BY t.LeadID, t.Email
    ORDER BY SUM(o.OutValue) DESC
```

Above will take like forever to run. Can someone please give some suggestions on how to optimize the above stored proc so we can get the results back within a reasonable timeframe? Thanks very much!

Comment: Having the 900 separate tables is killing you.  You need a consolidated campaign summary table that gets updated when each campaign ends so you can do your query in a single select.